# What is `tokenStandard` in On-Chain Metadata?

Tags: metadata, fungible-token, metaboss

I've been using MetaBoss to create fungible tokens. Here's an example of how I'm doing it:

`metaboss create fungible -d 9 -m onchain_metadata.json`

When I do, the `tokenStandard` in the token's metadata always gets set to `2`, even if I declare `tokenStandard` to be something else in my metadata JSON file.

When I look up what `tokenStandard` is, Metaplex documentation says that it describes the fungibility of the token, and some valid values for `tokenStandard` are `Fungible` and `Nonfungible`, but not `2`.

What am I missing here? Why does Metaboss assign the value `2` to `tokenStandard`? And does it even matter? Maybe I'm worrying about something that is irrelevant.

Thanks for your help! Here are links for reference.

Metaboss documentation: https://metaboss.rs/overview.html

Metaplex documentation on `tokenStandard`: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard

Example token I created: https://explorer.solana.com/address/BdRUndDzCkTMXipRKXir51iC4edTW26Q5prcGkosphVq/metadata?cluster=devnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2` is simply the encoded value for the `TokenStandard` enum in your token metadata. If we look at the code defining the enum at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/eb312662b0314b7043775b7c034298c76080cb52/programs/token-metadata/program/src/state/mod.rs#L68 we see:

```
pub enum TokenStandard {
    NonFungible,                    // This is a master edition
    FungibleAsset,                  // A token with metadata that can also have attributes
    Fungible,                       // A token with simple metadata
    NonFungibleEdition,             // This is a limited edition
    ProgrammableNonFungible,        // NonFungible with programmable configuration
    ProgrammableNonFungibleEdition, // NonFungible with programmable configuration
}
```

Counting up from 0, a value of 2 would mean `Fungible`.

I can't tell you why metaboss always uses `Fungible` as the token standard, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: This is spot on! I got the same answer from Metaplex team in their Discord.

They agreed that their docs are fuzzy here. The associated `int` values should be clearly correlated with the `str` values that they list.

With respect to the amazing Metaboss library, the `metaboss create` command is meant for fungible tokens, so it always assigns `2` as the `tokenStandard`.

You can use `metaboss mint` to create NFTs, which will have `tokenStandard: 0` :D

Comment: If you think it's useful to others, please accept / upvote so that others can find it in the future!